# Using Rationalize to find the exact rational form

Tags: conversion, number-representation

When I run

```
Rationalize[2.98688387095, 0]
```

I get $\frac{117300079}{39271724}$

However, when I run

```
N[117300079/39271724, 50]
```

I get

```
2.986883870949999546747680341204272060987
```

But what I really wanted was

```
2.986883870950000000000000000000000000000
```

How can I find the exact rational form of 2.98688387095?

Comment: Per the linked question, you could try `FromDigits @ RealDigits @ 2.98688387095`.

Comment: As I explain in my answer to the question linked by Carl, `Rationalize[num, 0]` doesn't give an exact rational conversion.  You instead need `Rationalize[num\`z,0]`, where (simplifying from my answer) z>= twice the number of digits in the number.  So, for your case, using a z of 100 (far more than enough), we have:  `x = Rationalize[2.98688387095\`100, 0]` and `N[x, 50] = 2.9868838709500000000....`